# What is a man that speaks without saying a word called?

Tags: adjectives

What is a man that speaks without saying a word called? I have searched for words that describe it but couldn't get a word that simply covers it.

Comment: How do you speak without saying a word?

Comment: He who speaks through a doll?

Comment: @Sankarane -  Ventriloquist ;-)

Comment: Chris - In your question you ask for a noun (a type of man), but your tag is 'adjectives'. Please can you give us a sample sentence with a gap where the word would go? Thanks.

Comment: That's right! But he still speaks through the doll :-)

Comment: An aphasiac? A reverse mind-reader? God? So many ways to interpret this seemingly self-contradictory question… voting to close as unclear.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because if there is an answer it's not about English, either in general or in particular; if there are many answers it's too broad or else opinion-based; and if there is no answer it's just an invitation for people to misinterpret the question (which, by the way is not altogether clear as to what you are asking).

Comment: Another ask and run user.... Voting to close because the answer could be anything, it could be a "telepathic", "ventriloquist", "deaf and dumb", "mute" "guru" for all we know.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I think he is specifically looking for a noun that expressly signifies an alternative mode of communication, other than talking. Out of all of your suggestions, only Telepath(ic) might apply. Both dumb and mute just say the person doesn't talk, without  specifying how or even if they communicate at all. A ventriloquist talks in a way that makes it seem like he's not talking but he is nevertheless talking. I suppose a guru could do this but it isn't inherent to the word's definition. Since this only has the adjective tag I might suggest tacit if I knew it could be applied to people.

Comment: @Tonepoet yeah, but until the OP actually *clarifies* we can "think" as much as we like, and technically a writer communicates without speaking too. The question deserves to be downvoted. Note that before the question was edited the title asked for an "adjective". This is a very bad question.

Comment: But if Chris Thompson clarifies and explains what he means by "speaking without saying a word" I'm ready to retract my downvote and my vote to close this question as being "unclear".

Comment: @Robusto: My vtc (and caveat) matches Mari-Lou's above. Assuming there *is* a meaningful question here, it's quite possible there's a clearly-identifiable answer (for example, a ***signer*** using ASL). The problem is the current wording is far too vague to pinpoint the exact intended sense (not that there are no potentially precise answers, once we know exactly what's being asked about).

Comment: OK dudes...the question is very clear. Maybe we should start with. 'One who talks to you without speaking is called what. I think that should help us cut corners.

Comment: @Chasly from UK, I could make a transcript from it and try to explain it all but I'd rather not confuse you or anyone on this matter. All I ask is that someone throw some light to this and give me his point of view. Thanks

Comment: @ChrisThompson - Well speaking for myself, I gave an answer (see below). You have given me no feedback on it so I have now lost interest. Good luck, I hope you find your answer.

Answer (score 1):

A **mime** or **mime artist**.

Also many deaf people use sign language so I guess they qualify as well.

Answer (score 1):

You mean a language which uses manual communication?  That is called **"sign language"** and those who use it are "sign language users", usually deaf people.

There is also **"body language"** (which is not the same as "sign language") where you convey what you mean by facial expressions, eye movements, body postures, sudden gestures.  Facial expressions can be very subtle and work best when two persons know each other very well. Those who use it very often can be said to be "body language users", though this is not a set phrase.

> - "sign language" - a system of hand movements used for communication especially by people who are deaf. [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sign%20language)
> - "body language" - the gestures, postures, and facial expressions by which a person manifests various physical, mental, or emotional states and communicates nonverbally with others. [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/body+language)

Comment: Great answer but I wonder if the OP is just toying with us...seems like a riddle.

Comment: I got this from a friend and wanna share. Non verbal body language....

Comment: Pls your discretion is advised